# ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known; fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

The process of setting up a GitHub account works just fine but it doesn't work when I try pushing my repository to GitHub. The error message it shows is as follows:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have tried changing RSA keys and all but still getting error.

What causes this error?

Comment: I have seen this problem too, but it seems to be intermittent - I waited 10 minutes then it went away

Comment: Not localized in the least.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15058758/266309) worked for me.

Comment: It seems like for me, github does not support cloning over ipv6. I forced ipv4 by modifying ~/.ssh/config (you will have to figure out the formatting by yourself since I can't do that in the comments):

    Host github.com *.github.com
      AddressFamily inet

Comment: As implied by one of the answers it can be a transient issue requiring no change on your part, but waiting for the issue on the side of github.com to resolve.

Comment: Facing the same issue. tried by changing the ssh key as well. doesn't worked by gitbash.

Comment: I saw this problem too. Was on my org vpn. Turning that off solved the issue.

Comment: just wait a few seconds and retry

Answer (score 143):

Recently, I have seen this problem too. Below, you have my solution:

1. ping github.com, if ping failed. it is DNS error.
2. sudo vim  /etc/resolv.conf, the add:
   nameserver      8.8.8.8
   nameserver      8.8.4.4

Or it can be a genuine network issue. Restart your network-manager using `sudo service network-manager restart` or fix it up

Comment: @JsonBruce and Fahmi: to know more about it why it worked read how DNS works, just to give you heads up, when you make any request it first checks the local cache for the "IP resolution" but if it's not there then it tries to resolve from nameserver configured in your /etc/resolv.conf (in case of UNIX/ Linux). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server

Comment: @FahmiRamadhan I believe that when github enables 3rd party DDOS protection their dns records and/or servers will change, above actions will flush your dns records, pointing you to the DDOS protected servers. (I've added this to my answer)

Comment: adding nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf` fixed the issue for me! Before it had only the router nameserver, which was apparantly not working correctly.

Comment: Resetting device Network works for me

Comment: faced it on ububtu 22.04 vm. reboot solved it.

Answer (score 72):

I have just received this error after switching from HTTPS to SSH (for my origin remote). To fix, I simply ran the following command (for each repo):

`ssh -T git@github.com`

Upon receiving a successful response, I could fetch/push to the repo with ssh.

I took that command from Git's [Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/) guide, which is part of the greater [Connecting to GitHub with with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/) guide.

Comment: Getting issues even after executing this command  
            $ ssh -T git@github.com
            git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: I was able to succeed in testing my connection, but fetch still failed with OP's error.  Turns out I had added ssh:// protocol to the SSH repo URL that GitHub gave me, and this caused it to fail.  Removing the old origin and re-adding using the exact SSH URL from GitHub fixed it.

Comment: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: this fixed my issue stat! thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Github is currently (on 22nd of feb 2012, again on 5th of sept 2016) having some problems with pushing/pulling over ssh.
I'm experiencing the same problems.

Pulling over https is working thought.

You can try pushing over https by following this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/

This would only help if https is not affected.
you can try and look at https://www.githubstatus.com/ to see if there are any reported issues at github's end.

If github is currently being DDOS'ed they may choose to enable DDOS protection from a 3rd party. This would mean they change their dns records and/or servers if these are part of the DDOS.

Flushing your dns, changing your dns server or restarting your network (which will possibly flush your dns cache) as stated in the other answer might help in fixing the issue for you if github is mitigating a DDOS.

Or if you have problems with your ssh setup you can find the ssh faq here: http://help.github.com/ssh-issues/

Other ways to flush your dns,
in windows in your terminal

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

on macos

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

on linux

```
service nscd restart
```

or simply rebooting ;)

Answer (score 9):

Each of this could help

1. Confirm if you are still connected using ssh.
   Type this:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

If you get the message that you were successfully authenticated and that GitHub doesn't support shell access, then you can try pushing your code again.

2. If the above did not work, create a new ssh key, add it to Github, and run the command again:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Comment: literally what is the "git@github.com", what should it be, give an example, there are email address, users names, repos that can be added in this infinite "git@github.com".  This is typical github, you need to read their minds.

Comment: Hi @BrianWiley, git@github.com is the email Github has provided for users to check if your generated SSH connection between your local machine and Github is working.

Comment: thanks i realized that since there was no <> you literally just type that

Comment: I am online as I am reading this, and I still have the error message while doing `ssh -T git@github.com`. This answer didn't helped me

Comment: I ran this and then it asked for my ssh password and after i typed that in I was able to use git again in my terminal

Answer (score 6):

I was having this exact issue and all that I had to do was to restart my desktop

Comment: After ping fails, I restarted the machine and everything works fine. +1

Comment: Yes, telnet and ping failed, no way to work, I restarted and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had misspelled something when manually adding the remote origin with `git remote add origin ...`.

It's worth checking your remote is correct with `git remote -v`

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this approach,

```
echo -e "[network]\ngenerateResolvConf = false\n" | sudo tee /etc/wsl.conf
echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\n" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

[Reference](https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter/608cfe02319ce60facd76373249b8ca6)

Comment: This solution is the one that worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows 10 and you are facing this error, try using `ssh -T git@github.com` to authenticate again to Github. It worked like charm for me.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes restarting your machine is also a good idea. When I faced the same issue after restarting the system, it told me that your private key is locked and github cant access that.. so enter your password to do that.. I entered the password and then the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can check which the key is being used by trying to connect to git@github.com:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
> ...
> debug1: identity file /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
> debug1: identity file /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
> debug1: identity file /Users/you/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
> debug1: identity file /Users/you/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
> ...
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
> debug1: Trying private key: /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa
> debug1: Trying private key: /Users/you/.ssh/id_dsa
> debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
> Permission denied (publickey).
```

In that example, we did not have any keys for SSH to use. The "-1" at the end of the "identity file" lines means SSH couldn't find a file to use. Later on, the "Trying private key" lines also indicate that no file was found. If a file existed, those lines would be "1" and "Offering public key", respectively:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
> ...
> debug1: identity file /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
> ...
> debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
> debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
> debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa
```

#### Verify the public key is attached to your account

You must provide your public key to GitHub to establish a secure connection.

1. Open Terminal.
2. Start SSH agent in the background.

   $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

   > Agent pid 59566
3. Find and take a note of your public key fingerprint.

   $ ssh-add -l -E sha256

   > 2048 SHA256:274ffWxgaxq/tSINAykStUL7XWyRNcRTlcST1Ei7gBQ /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
4. In the upper-right corner of any github page, click your profile
   photo, then click Settings.
5. In the user settings sidebar, click SSH and GPG keys.
6. Compare the list of SSH keys with the output from the ssh-add
   command.
7. If you don't see your public key in GitHub, you'll need to add your SSH key to GitHub to associate it with your computer.

Follow this [link](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey) for details

Answer (score 1):

I was using "WSL: Ubuntu" via VS code, closing my connection and then restarting worked for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

On centos 7

1. check ip address using command `ifconfig`. you will get information like this

   ```
   ens33: flags=****<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu ****

   inet ***.***.***.***  netmask ***.***.***.0  broadcast ***.***.***.***
   ```
2. add inet ip address and hostname in file `/etc/hosts`

   a. open file `vi /etc/hosts`

   b. add ip and host like `ip_address hostname hostname`
3. reboot

It will attach ip and host.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, tried all the methods nothing worked.

then realized my VPN was on.

if you too have a VPN turned on try switching off your VPN and retry.

I was using [Cloudflare VPN](https://1.1.1.1/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same output and turned out I had contradicting `insteadof` declarations in the `.gitconfig` (because I was working simultaneously on node and golang projects). You can manually delete the sections from the `.gitconfig`. Though I've created a script that cleans the url sections to be able to add the insteadof declarations on a cleaner config:

for windows (should be saved as `.bat`):

```
@echo off

setlocal

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (`git config --get user.name`)  do (
    set git_user=%%#
)

echo %git_user%

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=] " %%a in (`findstr "[url " "%userprofile%\.gitconfig" ^|find /V "%git_user%:" 2^>nul`) do (
     git config --global --remove-section url.%%b
)
endlocal

rem -- git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

git_user=$(git config --get user.name)


git config --global -l | grep -v $git_user | grep url.| awk -F '.insteadof' '{print $1}' | while read -r url ; do
    echo $url
    git config --global --remove-section $url
done
```

And it will be a good idea `.gitconfig` to be backed up.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to troubleshoot [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey)

This happen with me on SourceTree
In my case, something wrong with my pair public-private key. So I delete this pair(usually store on /Users/username/.ssh) and generate new one(also add SSH on github Settings-> SSH and GPG keys manually if needed)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), then your distro might have lost connection.

Following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578387/6950666) steps from another StackOverflow post helped my case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578387/6950666

Answer (score 0):

For me this resolved the issue:
`sudo systemctl restart networking`

Answer (score -1):

[image]

I've the same issue of recent to solve this problem all you just need to do is to connect to stable internet once you're connected to stable  internet try again

Comment: Please don't provide screenshots and replace it with text only.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32739800)

Answer (score -1):

restarting my terminal did not work, so i restarted my laptop ,and it works.

Answer (score -4):

If ping github.com gives below error:
ping: cannot resolve github.com: Unknown host

Kindly wait for couple of minutes and then try again.