# Could not resolve hostname, ping works

Tags: networking

I have installed RasPi Raspbian, and now I can't do ssh or git clone, only local host names are being resolved it seems. And yet ping works:

```
pi ~ $ ssh test.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname test.com: Name or service not known

pi ~ $ git clone gitosis@test.com:test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname test.com: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

pi ~ $ ping test.com
PING test.com (174.36.85.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I sort of worked around it for github by using `http://github.com` instead of `git://github.com`, but this is not normal and I would like to pinpoint the problem.

Googling for similar issues but the solutions offered was either typo correction, or adding domains to hosts file.

Comment: If you can ping, try using the IP address. `git clone gitosis@174.36.85.72:test.git`. I'd also take a look at `nslookup test.com` to ensure it resolves correctly.

Comment: Of course I could use IP address but I want to fix it once and for all. And most important - to understand what is causing it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This sounds like a DNS issue.  Try switching to another DNS server and see if it works.

OpenDNS

- 208.67.222.222
- 208.67.220.220

[GoogleDNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

Comment: Who could've thought! after using nslookup I saw there is some recursion going on: `;; Got recursion not available from 203.144.206.49, trying next server`, changing to Google DNS fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, it happens sometimes, especially when one thing seems to work.  Glad you got it working!

Comment: In my case, I've added the blow lines to /etc/resolv.conf:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 2):

Try reseting te contents of the DNS client resolver cache.
(For windows) Fireup a command prompt and type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

If you are a linux or mac user, they have their own way of flushing the dns.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, I just needed to specify a folder:

```
localmachine $ git pull ssh://someusername@127.0.0.1:38765
ssh: Could not resolve hostname : No address associated with hostname
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

localmachine $ git pull ssh://someusername@127.0.0.1:38765/
someusername@127.0.0.1's password:
```

That error message is just misleading.

Answer (score 0):

if you've a network-manager installed

check /etc/nsswitch.conf

if you've got a line

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

remove the **[NOTFOUND=return]**

restart /etc/init.d/networking

the [NOTFOUND=return] prevents futher lookups if the first nameservwe doesn't respond correctly
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a rare case, but in case your target server works on a non-standard port rather than 22 like mine, you need specify port like below:

```
ssh user@remote_server -p 2222
```

The port number should be passed to the command via `-p` argument. The error "could not resolve hostname" ocurred when I tryied to connect in this way: `ssh user@remote_server:2222`.

Answer (score -1):

This may be an issue with the proxy. Kindly unset and try.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```