# Could not resolve hostname git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: git

I tried doing `git pull --rebase` and I am getting the following error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried doing `git remote -v` and the origin is properly listed.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you show the output of your `git remote -v` command so we can make sure it's correct?  Sometimes simple things (typos) are overlooked.  Also, can you `ping git`?  Does ping find the host?

Comment: ping git does not work.

Comment: Then this looks like a network problem vs. a git problem.  Perhaps if you use the fully qualified host name?

Comment: BTW, is `git` the name of your server?  If not, then remote is not setup correctly.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git remote -v`? Or not, if after 2 years you don't care anymore :p

Comment: Have you added your ssh-keygen to your remote machine from where you are doing a git pull?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh: Could not resolve hostname \[hostname\]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-hostname-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-n)

Answer (score 11):

I have recently solved this issue by removing `ssh` from the remote address on my fork:

```
origin  ssh://git@ghe.company.net:yunus/client.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@ghe.company.net:yunus/client.git (push)
...
```

updated as:

```
origin  git@ghe.company.net:yunus/client.git (fetch)
origin  git@ghe.company.net:yunus/client.git (push)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the hostname to `/etc/hosts` file

```
# IP       hostname
1.55.4.5.66 hostname@host.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I had run into the same error.
Fix it by switching to another DNS server.

You can try [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

Get answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15058758/3675670)