# testing ssh connection error "ssh: Could not resolve hostname hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: ssh, git-bash

I am following this page on how to [test ssh connection](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection).

When i enter this first line:

```
$ ssh -T git@hostname
```

I get an error:

```
ssh: could not resolve hostname 
hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Note that by testing with ssh, you take Git completely out of the picture (which is a good thing, it reduces the complications by quite a bit). This proves that the problem is not related to Git.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you can `ping hostname`, meaning your DNS does resolve hostname into an IP address.

If not, then SSH would fold back to `~/.ssh/config`, looking for a `Host hostname` entry which would indicate what '`hostname`' actually means.

Of course, replace '`hostname`' by the actual remote host name you want to reach with this SSH session.

After that, it depends on your OS ([Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1717753/141), [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398188), ...), both for the source and the target.

Comment: ping hostname returns this: ping request could not find host hostname. please check name and try again. I went to my .ssh/ and there is no config file.

Comment: @J-Storm9 Do this is a DNS first issue (before SSH). You need to make sure the hostname can be resolved, or try its IP address directly.

Comment: @J-Storm9 If the IP passes, then you can add it to your [`/etc/hosts`file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62339310/6309).

Comment: how do i go about resolving the hostname?

Comment: @J-Storm9 First, it depends on the nature of your source and destination server (OS? Version? Git version?). Second, a typical test to check if the network route is opened is `curl -v telnet://hostname:22` (replacing hostname by the actual target host name, of course). If you know its IP address, you can do the same test with IP instead of hostname.