# Clone from GitHub.com "Temporary failure in name resolution" error

Tags: github

I encountered problems to download floodlight from GitHub. I have googled and tried various methods to clone it. Below is the error:

```
  mininet@mininet-vm:~$ git clone git://github.com/floodlight/floodlight.git
  Cloning into 'floodlight'...
  fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
  github.com:Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I'm currently running mininet in a virtual machine and i have tried with https/http instead of git. Still, I encountered errors when trying to download floodlight from GitHub.

My virtual machine network is connected with NAT and GitHub.com is up and running. However, when I tried to ping to GitHub.com it won't work. How do I resolve this DNS server issue?

Comment: can u open github on a browser? Do you use a proxy to connect? The proxy might be the problem, since the ping doesn't work either

Comment: Yes the proxy might be the problem. It's weird that I am able to open GitHub on a browser and not being able to ping them. I'm still figuring out how to fix it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: That's natural. git doesn't know about the proxy, although browser does

Comment: Duplicated and the most proper answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393409/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-github-com-name-or-service-not-known-fatal-th

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but found it to be intermittent. What I found to resolve the issue was the following:

1. Make sure you have the latest version of virtual box. The latest versions support ping from a NAT guest to the Internet - although I've had mixed success with that
2. If I was using a dongle connection to the Internet, i.e. not persistent, I found that I sometime s I had to reboot the guest, after the connection to the Internet had been made.

So nothing particularly technical, and ceratinly nothing to do with forwarding rules. But it worked for me,

michael

Comment: Same. I found restarting the virtual machine helped it.

Answer (score 1):

You must be behind a proxy

`git config --global http.proxy %HTTP_PROXY%` to configure the proxy to be the same as yoyur system proxy. IF `%HTTP_PROXY%` is not set(Try `echo %HTTP_PROXY%` if it echoes a hostname, no problem. If it echoes back %HTTP_PROXY%, you got a problem), try setting the proxy manuallt

`git config --global <Host>:<Port> (Generally 8080)`

IF you don't know the proxy, go to Internet Explorer>>Tools>Internet Options>>Connections>>LAN Settings
and check the proxy server address

IF its configured by a script such as .pac, open this file. there should be a function findProxyForUrl or something, its simple pythonish code. You should be able to figure it out from there.