# Push remote Repositories

Tags: git, github

In the process of Github setting (connect computer and github),there is error.

> λ git push -u origin master
>
> ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:account: Name or service not known
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

・I use my phone's tethering
・Windows10
・git remote →　origin
・git branch →　master
・Already committed

But, when I ping github.com, it returned
Request Timeout.(Even Tethering)

Could you help me with solving this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known; fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393409/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-github-com-name-or-service-not-known-fatal-th)

Comment: @Shun: Did you add the SSH key in your Git account? You have to add all SSH keys of all your machines in your Git account. You might need to generate the keys first if not available already. On Windows, you would be doing that using Git Bash.

Comment: @LexoAlonzo  Thanks guys! I solved this. I need to delete the hidden .git folder first. and need to use http url.

Comment: @Azeem thanks! same as above. I'm just a beginner, but I'm surprised at this kind community

Comment: You deleted the git folder? Did you not want it to be a git repo anymore?

Comment: @ShunIshikawa : You are welcome! Yes, you may use HTTPS url to work with Git. In case you want to use SSH, you have to add the SSH key to your GitHub account. Best of luck!