# No internet connection on WSL Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, connection, windows-subsystem-for-linux, failed-to-connect

Recently I installed **WSL Ubuntu 18.04** on my Windows machine, but nothing seems to work properly, because I have **no internet access**.
I tried a few commands and `sudo apt update` says 'Connection failed' and `ping google.com` literally takes forever as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

I also checked `nano /etc/resolv.conf` and made sure that the nameservers are right, completely disabled Kaspersky and its firewall, disabled Hyper-V, reinstalled WSL a few times and even disabled Windows Defender. Nothing helped.

So do you have any ideas what the issue could be here?

Comment: Can this question be migrated to the proper site instead of closed here?

Comment: "sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf" add 1.1.1.1, then ping google.

Comment: **TL;DR (also incomplete information below):** `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`, put `#` before existing entries, add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` on its own line, save (Ctrl+X; Y; Enter), `ping google.com` to make sure it worked, then to make sure it doesn't get overwritten: `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`, add `[network]` on its own line, then `generateResolvConf = false` on the next line, save, and you're done.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Open Command Prompt as an Administrator and type these commands:

```
netsh winsock reset 
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Reboot your machine.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3438#issuecomment-410518578

Comment: Yes it is working i had the same problem it helped me alot in fixing problem

Comment: Works after reboot, but if the network reconnects of if I disconnect and reconnect VPN the problem resurfaces.

Comment: Is step 5 a reboot of wsl or of the whole computer?

Comment: Flush the local network config just for wsl?

Comment: I tried the commands mentioned above but didn't fixed the issue for me

Comment: This is also useful for when you change ISP/wireless router.

Comment: @Alex I needed a full reboot.

Comment: Before you go too far, please make sure your %TEMP% folder is not in a non-standard location and that the WSL swap file (%TEMP%\ApppData\Local\Temp\swap.vhdx) is not compressed with NTFS compression.

Comment: Worked for me and now I need to figure out next how my antivirus can safely approve it.

Comment: For me it worked ONLY in combination of changing the nameserver of WSL after this process. I took it from powershell ipconfig /all, selecting the DNS of the VPN network

Comment: In my case the steps did not help but the following steps did:

1. sudo vi /etc/wsl.conf
2. Add the following entries into it:

[network]
generateResolvConf = false

3. sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
4. Remove all entries from there and replace them with:

nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8

You can of course add you own dns server instead of google.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sam. I hadn't been able to solve this for a couple of days. These commands and a full Windows reboot solved it.

Comment: This dint work for me, However it workded for my colleague.

Comment: After these commands + reboot WSL won't even start: Error: 0xc0000005
:(

Comment: This fixed my git connection over ssh to github.com in WSL2. Thank you so much!

Comment: I can confirm that it still works as of 9th August, 2023

Answer (score 529):

The reason this error occurs is because Windows automatically generates resolv.conf file with the wrong nameserver.

To resolve this issue, use the following steps.

1. Locate the file by running the following command:

   `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

> You will see the following in the file:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/resolv.conf
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver xxx.xx.xx
```

2. Change the nameserver value to `8.8.8.8` and save the file. You should now be able to connect to the internet.
3. If you are able to connect to the internet now then you may also need to stop WSL from resetting this file when opening future terminals. You can do that by running these commands:

   ```bash
   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
   sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
   sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
   sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
   sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
   ```

   (Special thanks to comments from @kanekotic and @Echo9k for this final step.)

Comment: This is the only correct solution for me. Just match it with your dns ip configuration on the main os.

Comment: this is a great answer the only thing i will add is you have to edit /etc/wsl.conf and add the next text to make the changes persistent
[network]
generateResolvConf = False

Comment: Here are the steps to prevent WSL 2 from overwriting it every time.  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420#issuecomment-646479747

Comment: This can't have been the solution for the question as there was name resolution. It's good it works for people but incorrect.

Comment: This worked for me, I also had to run `wsl --shutdown` in admin command prompt, then start Ubuntu again for it to work.

Comment: Not sure why this is trending but this didn't work for me and also the question poster mentioned he has checked dns and it was not the cause of the problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578387/11190169) is the corrrect one

Comment: probably trending since it was the answer for most visitors, including myself.  Still wondering why microsoft can't get this to work by default - or maybe it's the arch installer I used ?  Anyway glad it's working now

Comment: Just reset my WSL installation multiple times due to issues with Hyper-V, had no internet, saw this answer. Turns out, I had no `resolv.conf` file at all. Creating the file with just `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in it worked immediately.

Comment: The third comment that links to github.com is important. Without 'sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf' when the machine reboots, /etc/resolv.conf was deleted and was not re-generated.

Comment: I have tried this and the answers given below as well. Nothing worked except https://askubuntu.com/a/1264985
Solution : Seems to be related to VPN. I found out, that it only fails the DNS lookup when I first connect the VPN before starting WSL-Ubuntu after System-Reboot. First starting WSL-Ubuntu and afterwards connecting the VPN seems to work.

Comment: Wherever you are Jeffrey, you are a God to me. Saved me after an hour being stuck with this. 
Such a common problem out there and all answers seem to resolve around the ipv6 causing issues. Answer

Comment: That is the correct solution for me.

Comment: Making /etc/resolv.conf immutable can cause issues if any legitimate system process needs to update DNS settings, such as when changing networks or when a DHCP server provides new nameserver information. You should only make /etc/resolv.conf immutable if you are sure that your network setup will not need to change or be automatically updated.

Comment: I ran into a particular issue with Tailscale installed, but found a way around it: https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/2815

Answer (score 66):

Recipe which worked for me. (WSL2 + Cisco AnyConnect)

1. Connect VPN and get DNS servers list, we will need it later (execute in elevated PowerShell)

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerAddresses
```

2. Get search domain (execute in PowerShell)

```
Get-DnsClientGlobalSetting | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SuffixSearchList
```

3. Open WSL and run:

```
sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf # this will unlink the default wsl2 resolv.conf

# This config will prevent wsl2 from overwritting the resolve.conf file everytime
# you start wsl2
cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
EOF

cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.50... # The company DNS/nameserver from the command in step 1
nameserver 10.50... # The company DNS/nameserver from the command in step 1
nameserver 10.50... # list all nameservers from step 1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search this.searchdomain.com # The search domain that we got from step 2
EOF

# Make the new /etc/resolve.conf immutable
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

4. Change Cisco Anyconnect metric from default 1 to 6000 inside powershell

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
```

This needs to be done each time VPN connects. See here https://gist.github.com/machuu/7663aa653828d81efbc2aaad6e3b1431 how to automate this task.

5. Restart wsl2 on the same elevated powershell, then you can open up wsl2 and it should connect to the internet.

```
Restart-Service LxssManager
```

Taken here: https://jamespotz.github.io/blog/how-to-fix-wsl2-and-cisco-vpn

Comment: This is the only thing which worked for me. Especially step 4 seems necessary, I wonder what it does. Thanks.

Comment: What a life saver, I was able to get it to work on my work laptop finally.

Comment: This was the only hint that worked for me even without using Cisco VPN. So I left the Step 4. It seems that it is necessary to add the company and the external ns to get it working.

Comment: This was very useful, It helped me fix the WSL access to internet, even when I dont have a VPN set up (anymore)

Comment: With these changes internet stopped working on WSL completely, nice

Comment: Ok, managed to fix it. Somehow with these changes resolv.conf stopped generating completely, so I had to manually restore it. What did help is command from p4

Comment: I only had to add the correct `nameserver`s and `search` domain name to the `resolv.conf`. Many thanks!

Answer (score 40):

Copying the recipe that worked for me. 
Using WSL 2 on Windows 10.

Solution found at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5336#issuecomment-653881695

---

**Steps**

1. Open Powershell or Cmd as Administrator 
    and run each of these commands:

   ```
   wsl --shutdown
   netsh winsock reset
   netsh int ip reset all
   netsh winhttp reset proxy
   ipconfig /flushdns
   ```
2. Hit the Windows Key, 
   type `Network Reset`,

   hit enter.

   You should see this window.

   Click "Reset now".

   [image: Network Reset magic WSL fix]
3. Restart Windows

If you're lucky, WSL 2 should now be able to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

---

**Weird edge case**

For me I am still unable to ping sites, but internet seems to work everywhere else in WSL 2.

For instance, `ping stackoverflow.com` (or pinging any site) 
results in "100% packet loss".

However `curl --location stackoverflow.com -i` 
results in a successful response.

And `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` now works.

---

**Troubleshooting steps before finding the above recipe**:

Hadn't used WSL 2 in months, was trying to `sudo apt update` from a Debian distro's terminal when I discovered my internet wasn't working.

Spent an hour configuring my WSL's /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/wsl.conf and troubleshooting the auto-config bug (https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3928). Still didn't work.

Then I found this page. Tried the posted directions. Didn't work.

Finally found this posted solution, and WSL 2 suddenly works perfectly.

---

Took me hours trying to troubleshoot this, hope this is useful to someone someday.

Comment: Also mentioning : although not ideal, several users have reported they can use internet on WSL 1 but not on WSL 2 -- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4275

Comment: I can confirm that my linux subsystem have internet connection but DNS is broken. Your solution about changin /etc/resolve worked for me.

This WLS2 is behind a third party firewall.

Comment: I followed this and ended up bricking my WiFi for what it's worth.

Comment: @WillB3: Oh snap. Really sorry to hear that. In case I (or anyone else) runs into your issue in the future, could you please elaborate? How severe, and where?

Comment: Ended up being that I needed to turn WLAN AutoConfig back to "Automatic" Startup Type in Services. Not sure how many people would run into the same issue, but if you do, give that a shot.

Comment: This approach worked for me, but only in Command Prompt, not in Powershell.

Comment: you should have a corporate vpn working, that's why the ping command doesn't work. Your corporation has blocked all the ICMP protocol, and the PING command uses ICMP protocol.

Comment: Your answer led me down the rabbit hole from where I reached a successful solution. 
What worked for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1908#issuecomment-654349473

Comment: I have tried this and also changed `/etc/resolve.conf`  as mentioned in other comments, updated nameservers on windows host like suggested elsewhere nothing worked. Then I was told to **hard reset** by IT support by pressing and holding power button for 10 seconds. 

Then it worked!

Not sure if the changes I made were required. But I am not touching them!

Answer (score 28):

If you fixed it changing the DNS but WSL2 keeps overwriting keep reading.

1. Replace the nameserver
   Similarly to @Jeffrey Kilelo's

```sh
# Replace the nameserver
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf'
```

If you're getting **Operation not permitted**. Change it manually making use of `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

2. To prevent WSL 2 from overwriting this value run the following [commands](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5420#issuecomment-646479747):

```sh
# Turn off generateResolvConf
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: First, create `/etc/wsl.conf`, then reboot WSL `WSL --shutdown` - WSL will delete `resolve.conf` after this manipulation, and after that create a new resolve.conf. No `chattr` is required.

Answer (score 19):

For me this issue arise when I switch from one network to another. Lets say for example I was working at office wifi and then I went home and start using home wifi. The above https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578387/1409707 answer worked for me. It seems like this is an actual isse, so till Windows comes up with a solution I had to find an easier way to do it every time. I copied the commands and created a bat file, kept it on desktop. So, everytime I switch the wifi connection/network I run the bat file as administrator and restart the system. I hope this helps to someone who is trying to figure out why it is happening and how to know an easy way to fix it,(not a permanent) one though.

create a new .bat file with following contents.

I named my file as `networkreset.bat`

```
wsl --shutdown
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh winsock reset
shutdown /r
```

everytime you switch the wifi/network run the script as adminstrator and restart.

After restarting internet works on WSL on the connected network.

Comment: Interesting.... you have `netsh winsock reset` listed twice in the script.  Is that on purpose?  We should run that at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: Have you found any permanent solution? I tried everything but still, nothing worked.

Answer (score 19):

For me the nameserver was no more pingable. So I did the below and it worked for me.

- type "Turn Windows features on or off" in windows prompt, open the app [image]
- disable Linux subsystem in Windows features [image]
- disable hyper-v (all subcomponents) [image]
- Click "Ok" and follow to restart
- enable Linux subsystem in Windows features [image]
- enable hyper-v [image]
- Click "Ok" and follow to restart

Unfortunately I could not remove Ubuntu as that contained my work. I had tried everything in this and other stackoverflow posts, with no success.

But the above worked for me and without any loss of work.

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me !

Comment: After losing on this problem half of my working day, this what fixed it

Comment: Same for me, this was the solution! Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In my case if not on VPN, the internet on my WSL works. When I connect to VPN it suddenly stops working.
There is a relevant discussion (still open the day I'm posting) on internet loss on WSL while on VPN [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277).

This solution presented before for this question works but requires reboot:

```
netsh winsock reset 
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
```

The other solution presented before:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

with the change of the nameserver to 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1 or any other random address it does not work for me **while on VPN**.

What solved it though is a hybrid of this second solution and the discussion presented [above](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277):

Step 1:

**While on VPN** in Powershell:

```
ipconfig /all
```

Search for your adapter that is linked to your VPN connection. Usually you can find in the description something like

> "CISCO Anyconnect ..."

Search in that block the addresses of your DNS servers (for me first DNS server didn't work so I took the second)

Step 2:
Taken from that same discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277), in PowerShell:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000
```

Step 3:

**While on VPN** on my WSL :

```
$ sudo echo "nameserver <the DNS server address from point 1>" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

The drawback of this solution (as for the previous ones) is that you need to do it at every new launch of your WSL.
To make it a bit easier one can create a short .sh script to automate it.
On your WSL:

```
$touch restore_internet_connection.sh
$nano restore_internet_connection.sh
```

place the below text inside:

```
echo "nameserver <the output from point 1>" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Next time you have the issue you just repeat step 2 and:

```
$sudo restore_internet_connection.sh
```

Comment: right, VPN has to be carefully looked upon

Comment: YES! VPN does cause issues.
I my case I was facing the error while the VPN was connected. As soon as I turn the VPN off, it worked.

Answer (score 6):

So I don't know if this helps anyone, but I installed Docker on Windows and followed the Microsoft instructions to install the WSL2 engine as recommended by Docker.

Then installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with WSL2 and ran into exactly the same problem - no internet.  All I really want to be able to do is build some docker images to test, on my work laptop, so WSL2 with no internet was a total no go for me.

After a lot of poking around various forums and guides including this thread, here is what finally worked for me:

- I reinstalled Docker with WSL2
- I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the Microsoft Store, but set the WSL version to 1 using the command prompt as follows

This first command shows the list of distros:
**C:\users\xyz> wsl -l -v**

| NAME | STATE | VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ubuntu-20.04 | Running | 1 |
| docker-desktop-data | Running | 2 |
| docker-desktop | Running | 2 |

So now use the following command to set the WSL version - substitute your distro name and use 1 to switch to WSL v1

**C:\users\xyz> wsl --set-version**

Results

1. At this point I had a fully working Ubuntu distribution in WSL, with full access to the internet and none of the annoyances of not being able to access update archives etc. But, no connectivity between the Ubuntu distro and my Docker desktop.
2. To solve the last piece of the puzzle - I used the guidance provided on [this link](https://pscheit.medium.com/use-docker-for-windows-in-wsl-8fc96ece67c8) . Just follow the instructions directly from there - it is rather too long to reproduce here.

Bottom line:
I have a WSL1 Ubuntu distro, it connects to the internet and I can build docker images using the CLI in Ubuntu using Dockerfiles without any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE** - This fix addresses DNS resolution issues in WSL. Absurd settings might cause the WSL distro to not have any internet connection at all.

The fix is to set the DNS of your Ethernet/WiFi adapter to your preferred choice. WSL uses the DNS of your host machine. commands like `wget` were working for me, however the commands like `apt update` didn't seem to work - basically it couldn't resolve the ubuntu archive URL.

As seen in this image, the DNS value is empty. It's inferred from the DNS of the host machine.

[image: wsl_adapter_settings]

Here is the image for adapter properties of the host machine where the DNS is provided manually. If you choose the automatic DNS option for the **host**, some things might not work on the DNS provided by your ISP.

[image: host_adapter_settings]

It is recommended to use OpenDNS, Google DNS or CloudFlare DNS since these are quite fast and reliable. Use DNSBenchmark to find the fastest one for your connection. I would like to highlight that it is strictly your choice.

Answer (score 4):

Non from above worked.
But switching to WSL 1 worked!

so in PowerShell as an administrator:

```
wsl --set-default-version 1
```

then reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: This posted answer will help you convert existing distributions to version 1.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67836566/861778

Comment: This work for me too, but since I have to use Podman and they use wsl2 for virtualization I have to keep looking.... but why ot works on version 1 and not on 2 is really driving me nuts

Answer (score 4):

I used this answer to network restart several times, but the last time it didn't work.

It only returned to work after uncheck compression to 'Temp' folder (%TEMP%)

```
compact /u /s:"%TEMP%" /i /Q
```

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5336#issuecomment-770494713

And so, network restart steps.

Command line refer:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/26340-compress-uncompress-files-folders-windows-10-a.html

Comment: If you want to keep %TEMP% compressed, just decompress the WSL swap file: %TEMP%\ApppData\Local\Temp\swap.vhdx

Comment: According to my experience on Win10.21H2, One-time `compact /u %TEMP%\swap.vhdx` is not enough. I have to `compact /u %TEMP%\ ` , so that the %TEMP% dir itself is NOT marked compact. Otherwise, everytime we `wsl --shutdown` then start a WSL instance, the **%TEMP%\swap.vhdx** is re-created and inherit the compact flag from %TEMP% and the problem re-arise.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure NTFS compression is disabled for the following file:

```
%TEMP%\swap.vhdx
```

*(i.e., [normally](https://superuser.com/questions/217504/is-there-a-list-of-windows-special-directories-shortcuts-like-temp) {[2](http://web.archive.org/web/20120101144026/http://www.scriptlogic.com/support/CustomScripts/environmentVariableReference.html),[3](http://web.archive.org/web/20140804040959/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190899),[4](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)}: `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\swap.vhdx`)*

[image: File properties window for %TEMP%\AppData\Local\Temp]

This could also happen if you have moved your entire `%TEMP%` folder to another location.

References:

- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5437#issuecomment-849173909
- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5336

Comment: Thanks for posting this - saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I know this thread hasn't had much activity in a while.  I spent DAYS trying to fix this on a work laptop, because the corporate setup doesn't allow an 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) address, not only did I have to edit the WSL2 /etc/wsl.conf

```
#/etc/wsl.conf
[network]
generateResolvConf = False
```

I also had to write a PowerShell script to write from Windows into the WSL2 folder the actual DNS server address.  I don't know if it's because of how locked down my work PC is or what, but I can only use the DNS server my Windows machine uses, and WSL2 always pulls its own IP address to populate the resolv.conf file, which has no DNS server.

Anyone else suffering through this issue, here's how I fixed it.  Save this off as whatever you want (in my case, debian.ps1, run from a Admin PowerShell prompt ./debian.ps1), I am using an imported customized Debian Buster WSL2 distro set as default; if you're using something else not set as default, you'll have to change the last line (wsl.exe) to launch the correct distribution:

```
# Get the DNS server of the Windows machine, save into variable nameserver
$nameserver = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Query "Select dnsserversearchorder from win32_networkadapterconfiguration" | where {$_.DNSServerSEarchOrder -ne $null} | select -ExpandProperty DNSServerSearchOrder
# Convert nameserver object into a string
$nameserver = Out-String -InputObject $nameserver
# Run Set-Contents (sc) to write the resolv.conf file in a public location as it has DOS formatted line endings written by PowerShell, not readable by Linux
sc -Path 'c:\Users\Public\Documents\resolv.conf' -Value ('nameserver ' + $nameserver) -Encoding utf8
# Convert the DOS formatted file into UNIX format for WSL2 and write it in the proper place (\etc\resolv.conf, its primary location is \\wsl$\[distro_name] from Windows)
[string]::Join( "`n", (gc 'c:\Users\Public\Documents\resolv.conf')) | sc '\\wsl$\debian\etc\resolv.conf'
wsl.exe
```

Note if your distribution isn't under \wsl$\debian\ you'll need to change it to where it actually resides.  I know this is not pretty, and pulls from many different solutions posted all over the internet, but it's the only one that works with my corporate administered PC and group policies.  Hope this saves someone a lot of hassle on a company administered PC.  Note if you're connecting via VPN I don't think this will work - I also haven't tested in the office with Coronavirus, it's running on home WiFi.  There may be some adjustments needed if you're on a company network directly.

Comment: This actually worked for me; however, your `sc` abbreviation is not a valid alias for the `Set-Content` cmdlet. `SC` (`C:\Windows\System32\sc.exe`) is a command line program used for communicating with the  Service Control Manager and services. It is on the env path and `Get-Alias sc` does not return a positive response.

Comment: Also, the WSL path is `\\wsl.localhost` for example `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\etc`. However, I was not able to use `Set-Content` to write to the `resolv.conf`, but you can edit it with `sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf` and just paste the content.

Comment: Interesting, it works for me no problem just as I pasted it here.  I just run it from PowerShell with a: `.\debian.ps1` - likely your setup is different as the `Get-Alias sc` returns a valid handle to `Set-Content`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only solution for me was:

- uninstall any Ubuntu (18.10 and 20.04)
- remove Linux subsystem in Windows features
- restart
- enable Linux subsystem in Windows features
- restart
- Reinstall Ubuntu 20.04

This is with Win10 V1909 (OS Build 18363.1379). I had tried everything in this and other stackoverflow posts, with no success.

I'm only suggest the above steps as an absolute last resort.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, WSL network starts not working when I installed WSL2 requirements and upgraded my wsl to version 2.

It can resolve domain to IP but can't reach out to IP over internet.

I updated OS and wsl2 modules to latest and tried all workaround solutions but it didn't work.

Finally, I found the solution.

1. Go to Device Manager and check View > Hidden Device
2. Uninstall all Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extensions
3. Remove "Windows Sub-system for Linux" from Features
4. Restart
5. Add "Windows Sub-system for Linux" from Features

For me, distro remained as version 2 after that, but it's working!
It's worth to try.

Answer (score 2):

I installed wsl and Ubuntu 20.04.

After troubleshooting for days, this is what worked for me.

I want to believe that those experiencing this issue like me are running wsl version 2.

This issue was resolved as soon as I switched back to wsl version 1 without the need for further configuration.

To see how to effect this change, kindly follow follow this link [Change wsl version](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/164318-how-set-linux-distribution-version-wsl-1-wsl-2-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had ufw installed on WSL2 with debian 10, after removing it and restarting Windows it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This happenned to me when I was trying to install MySQL-Server on WSL2 and messed up with ssh@local host trying to access root on Ubuntu.
The system itself got really weird (Sometimes I wish there were alternatives for Ubuntu) so I tried restarting the vEthernet(WSL) adapter and rebooting the computer, and it was back working again.

Answer (score -3):

You can solve this problem by just type this command in your terminal

-> sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Comment: Please note that this is WSL, which does not support systemd out of the box.  Thus systemctl will not work.

Answer (score -4):

For me, it was an issue with VPN service (NordVPN service) which cause many problems.
Just stop its service from **services.msc**.

Comment: This helps only if you don't really need that VPN connection. But what if you need exactly that VPN to get to a certain page, from WSL?