# Still able to use Explorer to view WSL files after reverting from WSL2 to WSL1 – is this normal?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am a big fan of Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and was totally psyched when they announced WSL2. However, the official Docs said that WSL2 isn't as performant as WSL1 when it comes to working with files in the Windows File system. This is kind of a bummer because most of my work is in the Windows File System itself and I would like to keep it that way.

But for the sake of checking it out, from PowerShell (could also be run from `cmd.exe`) I converted my main Distro to WSL2:

```
wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 2
```

The conversion was successful. Then – from WSL, logged in as *root* – when I ran

```bash
cd
explorer.exe .
```

it launched File Explorer in `Network\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\user`. I knew that this is a feature in WSL2; that we could access the Linux file system using the Windows Explorer.

However, I then decided to revert back to WSL1 (file system access). So I ran the command:

```
wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 1
```

And just to cross check, running

```
wsl.exe --list --verbose
```

lists my main distro as running version 1.

But now if I head over to WSL and run `cd ~; explorer.exe .`, it still opens up the directory in the File Explorer! As far as I know, this normally gives the error that windows can't access file paths with the Linux structure or something like that when run with WSL1.

So I was wondering if this is normal, or did it happen because of the reversion, or did I somehow break my installation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds "Normal" to me.  Support for accessing WSL files safely from Windows was added to WSL1 in Windows 10 version 1903 a bit over a year ago.  See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/

I guess I'm more surprised that you received an error message with 2004 when trying to access WSL1 from Explorer.  Perhaps you were just assuming it would still fail from your experience pre-1903?

Comment: For future readers, I'm honestly confused by the number of upvotes on this answer.  If you really were wondering if Explorer can view WSL1 files, then great - I'm glad I've answered that for you as well.  But if you came here looking for information on *how* to revert from WSL2 to WSL1 (the original question *title*, but not the actual question), then that information is all contained in the question itself, so please direct your upvote *there* instead of on my answer!

Comment: And also apologies, I just noticed this is on Stack Overflow.  Given the subject matter, it's really *very* off-topic here, and should have been posted on Super User.  When I answered this, I was pretty new to Stack Overflow.  Nowadays, I would have voted-to-close, but I didn't know better myself when I originally answered.

Answer (score 18):

Type this command to grab the version of distro

```
wsl -l -v
```

Then type this command to roll back / set default version

```
  wsl --set-version Ubuntu-20.04 1
```

It will output something like - **Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...**

Then try **wsl -l -v** command again, and check the result

In my case results before and after are

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         2
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

and after

```
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04           Stopped         1
  docker-desktop         Stopped         2
  docker-desktop-data    Stopped         2
```

EDIT

**Actually I read description of the question, after leaving this comment, and I guess I'm not answering on it at all, but I have decided to leave it here, because it can be helpful for someone who are trying to figure it out!**

Comment: For those upvoting this answer, please note that all of the information in it is *in the question* itself, so you should upvote the question rather than the answer if it helped you.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds You are upvoting questions rather than answers, whenever getting answers to your question? People are upvoting whatever they find helpful!

Comment: Sorry, no offense, but as you said, you didn't answer the question being asked; your answer just repeated everything the OP of the question had done leading up to their actual question.  That's *not* helpful, IMHO.

Comment: And it it matters, I'll be adding a similar comment on my answer.  I can't imagine that my answer has been helpful to 9 people.  It's more likely that they should have been upvoting the question instead.

Comment: Don't worry, people will upvote your answer too :)