# Unable to update the packages on WSL distribution

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Docker desktop v2.3.0 and I enabled WSL2 on Windows 10 Professional v1909.

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 distribution, I accessed it and when I run `apt-get update`:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried to update the `/etc/resolve.conf` by adding the company dns server after using `ipconfig /all`.

Then I rebooted the WSL but does not work.

I found a similar question [No internet connection on WSL Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314789/no-internet-connection-on-wsl-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux) and tried this [solution](https://gist.github.com/coltenkrauter/608cfe02319ce60facd76373249b8ca6) but none of them fixed the issue for me.

I use a proxy to access the internet, can it forbid the WSL from accessing the external network and should add it the wsl config file?

Comment: I hope the person flagged the question or the maintainer who closed it adds a comment about the reason of closing it. Many people in the community and allover the world face the same issue with WSL and no clear and detailed answer about the issue.