# No internet connection on WSL (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a similar problem as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314789/no-internet-connection-on-wsl-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux). But the algorithms that are described there (the main one is presented below) do not help to solve the problem of the lack of Internet on the system:

1. Open Command Prompt as an Administrator
2. `netsh winsock reset`
3. `netsh int ip reset all`
4. `netsh winhttp reset proxy`
5. `ipconfig /flushdns`
6. Reboot machine

This is what I get on the command `sudo apt update`:

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem?