# Content too short error while using Buildozer with a kivy-python application

Tags: android, windows-subsystem-for-linux, packaging, ubuntu-20.04, buildozer

I'm trying to package my application to an apk using Buildozer. I got WSL and Ubuntu working, along with buildozer and most of the dependencies. When I run `buildozer android debug deploy run` or `buildozer -v android deploy run` the Ubuntu console tries to install the Android NDK and eventually fails. It will download to about 25%-40% and then the error shown in the screenshot will display.

I've tried disabling my firewall, and I've also tried this solution even though I do have internet: [No internet connection on WSL Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314789/no-internet-connection-on-wsl-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Please let me know if you need any more information, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed the dependency without running Buildozer and made sure it was in the Buildozer directory. Fixed the issue.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  Just a couple of recommendations -- First, you might not have gotten much attention on this question due to the screenshot.  See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933) for details.  Second, for similar reasons, it would be useful to provide the actual commands/packages you used to satisfy the dependencies.  This information might be buried in the screenshot as well, but it would be useful to have in the answer, I believe.