# Unable to download/ use git in Ubuntu WSL

Tags: git, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently tried setting up WSL using Ubuntu however as I try to download things using terminal commands it just gets stuck. Depending on how lucky I am it will download portions and then just stop. In this image, I tried installing NVM following the instructions on GitHub with no success.
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjAaD.png)

I then tried spamming it and got "lucky" when the download was completed but nothing happens then it just timed out. Here I also tried downloading ohmyzsh.
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWdZj.png)

I've read around and it could be a network issue? Maybe a git issue or both? Git doesn't work for me (worked once or twice then stopped working). It too also gets stuck. (First one is clone using HTTPS second is SSH)
[Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z29bm.png)

I tried reinstalling Ubuntu with no success. Don't really know what to do. Expected it to just work.

Comment: Are you doing this on a corporate VPN? Such commands sometimes require I disconnect from my corporate VPN to work, they're just too slow otherwise and I get symptoms just like you describe. My advice is to try it on a different network configuration if you can, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Besides the possible VPN issues, there are known driver bugs in WIndows that cause corruption of TCP data with certain kinds of hardware when they're configured to do checksum offload. Setting up a network monitor with tcpdump or wireshark is a good way to capture and debug network issues, although it's almost always slow and painful.

Comment: I just ran into this issue today, had tried to update configs and what's funny is that it got resolved when I switched to connect to another router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, it was indeed a network issue. After checking network settings I found that it said WSL had no internet connection and did some reading and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63578387/20789584) which was the solution (however the network thing still says WSL no internet connection but everything works so idk)