# podman wsl communication issue

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, podman

I am switching from docker to podman currently. Usually that works just fine. However on one of my many company laptops I ran into the following error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> podman pull quay.io/podman/hello
Trying to pull quay.io/podman/hello:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://quay.io/podman/hello:latest: pinging container registry quay.io: Get "https://quay.io/v2/": dial tcp 54.163.152.191:443: i/o timeout
```

The above error I also get with other container registries. I tried:

Tried:

1. podman machine set --rootful
2. removing hyper-v and wsl
3. changing resolv.conf and adding nameserver
   (tried also 8.8.8.8)
4. looked into symantec endpoint protection logs
   (connection is not blocked)
5. switched between wsl 1 and 2
6. also tried some stuff from this thread (cf. [No internet connection on WSL Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314789/no-internet-connection-on-wsl-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux))

I also do not get any internet inside e.g. an Ubuntu WSL VM. In Powershell running e.g. curl google.com works just fine

For completeness sake with the third option changes I get:

```
podman pull quay.io/podman/hello
Trying to pull quay.io/podman/hello:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://quay.io/podman/hello:latest: pinging container registry quay.io: Get "https://quay.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup quay.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Update:
I reinstalled Docker and get a similar issue

```
docker container run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: initializing source docker://hello-world:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue with **podman** on my laptop with windows 11 OS.
Running the below commands in the command line fixed the issue.

```
wsl -d podman-machine-default
cd /mnt/wsl/
sudo chmod 777 resolv.conf
sudo printf "nameserver 8.8.8.8\n" >> resolv.conf
exit
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same issue. For me, VPN is blocking the internet connection in WSL2. The same works in WSL1

Explore this wsl-vpnkit from this github(https://github.com/sakai135/wsl-vpnkit/releases/), it resolved my issue.