# failure to complete the download of Mojo SDK

Tags: mojolang

when I switched to WSL(from windows) and ran:

`curl https://get.modular.com | \ MODULAR_AUTH=###################### \ sh -`

multiple times the download process stopped within seconds:

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3176  100  3176    0     0   6003      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6003

I expected the download process to complete!!!

any solutions?

Comment: Can you connect to the internet from WSL otherwise? Wonky internet connections are a known issue for WSL (see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62314789/15704972)

Comment: How about use [this guide](https://developer.modular.com/signup) and install it in vscode code space?

Comment: you should not post the modular auth="....."

Comment: what is your windows edition

Comment: The MODULAR_AUTH is posted on the mojo website as part of the installation