# Laravel Installation: Could not resolve host: laravel.build

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to install Laravel the Docker way on Windows, but getting an error. I'm just taking instruction directly from the docs.

This is the Ubuntu terminal on my Windows 10 (as instructed):

```
$ curl https://laravel.build/example-app | bash   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:09
--:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: laravel.build
```

It's the same URL from the docs - https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#sail-on-windows. I removed the S flag from the curl call to see the error.

Comment: are you sure if your internet is working within your Ubuntu system?

Comment: Damn. `$ ping google.com ping: google.com:      Temporary failure in name resolution` Thanks, this post then helped me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314789/no-internet-connection-on-wsl-ubuntu-windows-subsystem-for-linux