# ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution fatal error

Tags: github

I get this error when I am trying to push changes up to github:

ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I used to be able to push on this repo, but for some reason its giving me this error now.
When I run git remote -v it gives me this

origin  git@github.com:WilliamLi10/UnigraderBackendCode.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:WilliamLi10/UnigraderBackendCode.git (push)

I am trying to push changes up from my local repo to github, but it gives me this error.

Comment: Check first [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9393409/6309)