# fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Git push error

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

In the past I could use git bash and git desktop applications. I have decided to use after some time gitbash to improve my skills and trying to push changes on my local to the server.

I have realized I can't push anything even on extensions on my editors and I decided to try with the most basic steps and I'm getting this error.

**ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:firstcontributions: Name or service not known**

**fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

I have tried many solutions such as changing it to the from https to ssh
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:cagataysen/first-contributions.git
but after trying this command:
git push --set-upstream origin cagatay-first-contribution
I still get
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

After checking this error message on google:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

I followed the steps:
To make sure you are connecting to the right domain
I texted this command:
$ ssh -vT git@github.com

after many debugging messages I got this.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories

I have realized something is wrong with my remote-repository settings and tried this forum but result didn't change.

I removed my account and password from my credential manager on Windows.

I have tried to adding SSH key to my profile via SSH and GPG keys part. While using this instructors:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases

I think I can't detect my exact problem at the end of the day and looking for a solution. Thanks indeed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: Does it always say "could not resolve github.com"?

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes, when I'm trying to push, I get:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:firstcontributions: Name or service not known

fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I have changed it from https to ssh after reading on forums, but at last I got this.

Comment: If you get "could not resolve github.com" every time, then *that* is the important part of the error message - your computer is unable to translate `github.com` to a valid IP address. What do you get for `dig +short github.com`?

Comment: @JimRedmond bash: dig: command not found

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393409/ssh-could-not-resolve-hostname-github-com-name-or-service-not-known-fatal-th ?

Comment: @pptaszni Unfortunately I have been in this solution before and didn't work neither. I am getting replies from ping github.com